# Electromagnetic Radiation of Charged particles

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

This question is motivated by [similar one.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71947/does-a-charged-particle-revolving-around-another-charged-particle-radiate-energy) 
If an accelerated point charge $q$ radiates with power $W$ then I assume the same particle with charge $-q$ will radiate with the same rate $W$. Now what if we make a dipole with these two charges and accelerate it with the same acceleration? What will be the radiation power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this paper, [New approach to the classical radiation fields of moving dipoles](http://www.joseheras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/JH9.pdf), the answer is:

$P = \dfrac{18d^2a^4}{35c^7} + \dfrac{2d^2\dot a^2}{15c^5}$

Here, $d$ is the fixed electric dipole moment and the acceleration, velocity, and dipole moment are along the $z$ axis.

From the paper:

> This formula may be considered as the dipole analogue of the Larmor
>   formula of the point charge.

And the Larmor formula for a point charge is:

$P = \dfrac{2q^2a^2}{3c^3}$

Comment: The link doesn't work for me

Comment: @LarryHarson, thanks for the heads up.  Funny, I tried the link while I was editing and it worked but anyhow, it's fixed now.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, Thanks, nice answer. This result looks a bit puzzling to me!